# Getting CORS error in Edge/Firefox despite adding headers in nginx config

Tags: nginx, cors, fetch

I am making an API request to a server which has nginx configured. In the config file for nginx I added

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*'
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*'
```

and restarted nginx on the server.
I can see these headers when I curl to the server with the -v flag. But for some reason when I use a browser such as Edge or Firefox I get "Access to fetch from  has been blocked by CORS policy. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

I've tried it on an incognito/private browser window and still same issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Nginx has to be compiled with http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpHeadersModule (default on Ubuntu and some other Linux distros). Then you can do this

```
#
# Wide-open CORS config for nginx
#
location / {
     if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        #
        # Om nom nom cookies
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        #
        # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
        #
        # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
     }
     if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
     }
     if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
     }
}
```